# could not load func glGetActiveUniform in android emulator

Tags: android

I Geeta gond, I have a problem when i m lunching the project then emulator is start but before completion error is occured. "could not load func glGetActiveUniform
could not load func glGetAttachedShaders
could not load func glGetAttribLocation
could not load func glGetProgramiv
could not load func glGetProgramInfoLog
could not load func glGetShaderiv
could not load func glGetShaderInfoLog
could not load func glGetShaderSource
could not load func glGetUniformfv
could not load func glGetUniformiv
could not load func glGetUniformLocation
could not load func glShaderSource
could not load func glStencilMaskSeparate
could not load func glBlendEquationSeparate"

like these type of error is comming, I don't why.

plz suggest me regarding that.

"Thanks"

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when I installed Intel's latest graphics driver on a box with a Q33 express chipset.  The driver supports higher chipsets with OpenGL 2 support, but because the Q33 doesn't support OpenGL 2, I ended up having to revert back to the ealier driver to eliminate that error.

ARM's OpenGL ES 2.0 emulator works by translating those instructions to OpenGL 2.0 before passing them on to the graphics adapter.  I'm assuming that the GPU emulation on AVDs (4.0.3 and later) work on the same principle.  Therefore, I conclude that OpenGL ES 2.0 code will not work on an AVD if the box's graphic card chipset and driver don't support OpenGL 2.